# Spring Integration Test: Can not find bean for class in dependent module

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

My `project` structure looks like

```
project/pom.xml
       /external_services/pom.xml
                         /ifs/pom.xml
                             /src/main/java/
                                           /IFSClient.java
                                           /RestIFSClient.java

                             /src/test/java/
                                           /MockIFSClient.java
       /inventory/pom.xml
                 /business/pom.xml
                             /src/main/java/InventorySummary.java
                 /services/pom.xml
                             /src/main/java/InventorySummaryResource.java
                 /integration/pom.xml
                             /src/main/java/InventoryIT.java
```

**IFSClient** looks like

```
@Component
public interface IFSClient {

    @Nonnull
    InventoryPriceDetail getInventoryAndPrice(@Nonnull final IFSRequestPresentation ifsRequestPresentation);
}
```

**MockIFSClient** and **RestIFSClient** has details about how this method will return

**InventorySummaryManager** looks like

```
@Component
public class InventorySummaryManager {
    private final IFSClient ifsClient;

    @Autowired
    public InventorySummaryManager(@Nonnull final IFSClient ifsClient) {
        this.ifsClient = ifsClient;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public InventorySummaryPresentation getSummary(@Nonnull final InventorySummaryPresentation inventorySummaryRequest) {
        final InventoryPriceRequest inventoryPriceRequest = new InventoryPriceRequest(inventorySummaryRequest.getStartDate(),
                inventorySummaryRequest.getEndDate(), inventorySummaryRequest.getNetworkId());

        final IFSRequestPresentation ifsRequestPresentation = getIfsRequestPresentation(inventoryPriceRequest);
        final InventoryPriceDetail inventoryPriceDetail = ifsClient.getInventoryAndPrice(ifsRequestPresentation);
        return getInventorySummaryResponse(inventorySummaryRequest, inventoryPriceDetail.getInvListPriceData().get(0));
    }
```

**business/pom.xml** has dependency on `ifs` as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.org.inventory_api.external_services</groupId>
    <artifactId>ifs</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**integration/pom.xml** has dependency as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.org.inventory_api.external_services</groupId>
    <artifactId>ifs</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.org.inventory_api.inventory</groupId>
    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

and **services/pom.xml** has dependency as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.org.inventory_api.inventory</groupId>
    <artifactId>business</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

when I start my integration tests using `maven-cargo-plugin`, I see errors in logs as

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inventorySummaryManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/harith/IdeaProjects/inventory_api/inventory/integration/target/cargo/configurations/tomcat7x/webapps/inventory/WEB-INF/lib/business-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/org/inventory_api/inventory/business/InventorySummaryManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.org.inventory_api.external_services.ifs.IFSClient]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.org.inventory_api.external_services.ifs.IFSClient] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Nonnull(when=ALWAYS)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.org.inventory_api.external_services.ifs.IFSClient] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Nonnull(when=ALWAYS)}
```

I am not sure why this bean dependency can not be resolved, can someone please try to correct me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that out

My `application-context.xml` was scanning only `inventory` module before

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.org.project.inventory"/>
```

I changed it to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.org.project"/>
```

and the error was gone